# Postgresql where statement across tables with different column aliases

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, information-schema

This doesn't seem to be a common use case, but one that I run into frequently. I have multiple tables with similar structure but different column aliases. For example `day` vs `date`. This makes it difficult to have common `WHERE` statements.

I'm curious if there is a way to check and account for this in an automated way.

Say a sample of, `table 1` looks like this -

```
day         id
2021-01-01  book
2021-02-01  movie
```

And a sample of `table 2` looks like this -

```
date         idd
2021-01-01   book
2021-02-01   movie
```

And `table 3` has same structure as `table 1`

```
day         id
2021-01-01  book
2021-02-01  movie
```

So the data exists the same way, but the column name is different. How could I go about creating a common `WHERE` statement that would work for both of these tables. Checking whether `day` exists if so then `day` if not then `date`?

I would like to be able to use the same `SELECT WHERE` statement for both.

Comment: what your query look like before where?

Comment: so ```SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE day or date ...``` or also can do ```SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE day or date``` so the ```WHERE``` syntax is consistent